# Java DynamicReports format dates regarding to locale

Tags: java, jasper-reports, date-formatting

I'm using *DynamicReports API* for building reports.

I'm setting the *Locale* of the report and format the Date columns of the report, but the Dates are always formatted like *10/12/2009 10:54:44* AM no matter what the *Locale* is.

The code looks like:

```
rep.setTemplate(Templates.reportTemplate.setLocale(res.getLocale()));
...
if (rs.getString(i).contains("00:00:00"))
   rep.addColumn(col.column(title,  name,  type.dateType()));
else
   rep.addColumn(col.column(title,  name,  type.dateYearToSecondType()));
```

Is there a way to automatically format dates regarding to the *Locale* of the report or have I to use a custom ***ValueFormatter***?

Comment: Have you tried to instead adding it to the Parameter map as the `JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also tryed the Parameter Map with no success

```
JasperReportBuilder rep = report()
   .setDataSource(query, conn.getConnection())
   .setParameter(JRParameter.REPORT_LOCALE, res.getLocale());
   .setTemplate(Templates.reportTemplate.setLocale(res.getLocale()));
```

There is no way to automatically format the dates.
The only way is to use patterns for the date column in respect to the locale.

```
TextColumnBuilder<Date> column = col.column(title,  name,  type.dateType());
if (res.getLocale().equals("EN") {
  column.setPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");
}
else if (res.getLocale().equals("US") {
  column.setPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
}
else {
   ...
}
rep.addColumn(column);
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to format the date field in dynamic jasper in this way.

```
ColumnBuilder time = ColumnBuilder.getNew();
time.setTitle("Login Time");
time.setWidth(200);
time.setColumnProperty("emp.logintime", Date.class.getName()).setPattern("dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a");
drb.addColumn(time.build());
```